# How to save contact Details using flutter

Tags: flutter

I am working on a simple project which is help to save your contact number.So in my project contains two Text Field widgets which is used to enter the number and name and another have Raised Button which use to Save entered name and number.
**In my project functionality is that when i pressed the save button than entered name and number save into my mobile contact list**. how can i implement this functionality using flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Use [flutter_contact](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_contact) plugin from pub.dev.

Following methods should help you (read docs for more info).

```dart
// Add a contact  
// The contact must have a firstName / lastName to be successfully added  
await Contacts.addContact(newContact);  
  
// Delete a contact
// The contact must have a valid identifier
await Contacts.deleteContact(contact);  

// Update a contact
// The contact must have a valid identifier
await Contacts.updateContact(contact);

/// Lazily fetch avatar data without caching it in the contact instance.
final contact = Contacts.getContact(contactId);
final Uint8List avatarData = await contact.getOrFetchAvatar();
```